# Bug identification

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Germany, cca 0.6mm, dead Bug, i haven't see before[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an immature cockroach, possibly *Planuncus vinzi*.
Here is a map of the observed distribution of the Planuncus genus:
[image: iNat map]

And here is an extract of a gallery of nymph-stage Planuncus cockroaches:
[image: iNat Gallery]

To view the full gallery: https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/732965-Planuncus/browse_photos?term_id=1&term_value_id=5
You can change the "Life stage" attribute from 'nymph' to 'adult' to see what the fully-grown versions look like and see whether they look more familiar to you in that form.